# Sum of an arbitrary number of random variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I'm trying to sum an arbitrary number of random variables (in this case, 3, but I'd like to be able to easily vary that)...

this does not work

```
aD = ExponentialDistribution[a]; 
zD = TransformedDistribution[Sum[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 3}], 
  Distributed[Subscript[x, i], aD]]
Mean[zD]
```

but this does

```
aD = ExponentialDistribution[a]; 
zD = TransformedDistribution[
  Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2] + Subscript[x, 3], 
     {Distributed[Subscript[x, 1], aD], 
   Distributed[Subscript[x, 2], aD], Distributed[Subscript[x, 3], aD]}]
Mean[zD]
```

Any suggestions on how to do this nicely?
(BTW, v 13.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use

```
PetersDistribution[n_,a_]:=Module[{x},
   TransformedDistribution[Total[Array[x,n]],
       Array[Distributed[x[#],ExponentialDistribution[a]]&,n]]];
```

For example

```
PetersDistribution[7,a]
(* ErlangDistribution[7,a] *)
```

**Note.** The answer seems to be `ErlangDistribution[n,a]` here, but I assume OP wanted to see the code and perhaps use it in some other case.

Comment: Correct - I _was_ looking for the general case. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

aD = ExponentialDistribution[a];

zD[n_Integer?Positive] := TransformedDistribution[
  Sum[x[i], {i, n}], Table[Distributed[x[i], aD], {i, n}]]

zD /@ Range[4]

(* {ExponentialDistribution[a], ErlangDistribution[2, a], 
 ErlangDistribution[3, a], ErlangDistribution[4, a]} *)
```

`ErlangDistribution[1, a]` is equivalent to `ExponentialDistribution[a]`, i.e.,

```
Assuming[x > 0, 
 PDF[ErlangDistribution[1, a], x] == PDF[ExponentialDistribution[a], x] // 
  Simplify]

(* True *)
```

For a proof by induction,  assume that `zD[n] == ErlangDistribution[n, a]`, the distribution for `zD[n+1]` is then

```
TransformedDistribution[x + zDn, {
  Distributed[x, ErlangDistribution[1, a]],
  Distributed[zDn, ErlangDistribution[n, a]]}]

(* ErlangDistribution[1 + n, a] *)
```

Since it is true for `n == 1`, by induction

```
zD[n_Integer?Positive] := ErlangDistribution[n, a]
```

Comment: +1. Nice and strong and accurate.

Answer (score 2):

A variation using `Through` follows:

```
    Clear[aDist, n, a];
    aDist[n_, a_] := TransformedDistribution @@ Through[{
         Plus @@ # &
         , Map[Distributed[#, ExponentialDistribution[a]] &] 
         }[Array[x, n]]]

aDist[4, a]
```

> ErlangDistribution[4, a]

```
Mean[%]
```

> 4/a